# How to handle different keyboard action in Anrdoid app?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, onkeydown

I have attached a physical keyboard to an Android tablet using USB. How can I call a function or perform some action in an Android app on pressing a paticular key, for example when pressing the zero key?

How could I implement the below code (for the zero key)?

```java
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            {
                // your Action code
                return true;
            }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Override `onKeyDown()` and similar methods in your `Activity` to respond to keypresses.

Comment: can you please leave me example ...

Comment: how can i create a listener .. eg key pressed from keyboard  lets say no zero

Answer (score 0):

It was such a silly mistake i didnt import Keyevent ..